# Calling React hook in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a chance I can run a query with a `useQuery` hook only if the button is clicked?

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const [, { data }]  = useLazyQuery(GET_ORDER_INVOICE, {
    variables: { order_Id: orderNumber }
  });

  return '';
};

<Button
  priority={ButtonPriority.SECONDARY}
  onClick={ () => {
    handleClick();
  } }
/>
```

However, this breaks with the React Hook "useLazyQuery" is called in function "handleClick" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. Is there a chance I can bind calling a query to a button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `useLazyQuery` in the body of your component. It will then return to you a function that you can call in `handleClick`:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [executeQuery, { data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_ORDER_INVOICE);

  const handleClick = () => {
    executeQuery({
      variables: { order_Id: orderNumber }
    })
  }

  // ...
  <Button
    priority={ButtonPriority.SECONDARY}
    onClick={handleClick}
  />
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this useLazyQuery be called on component render?

Comment: Yes, it should be called on render, and that's what my code does. Does that answer your question, or did i misunderstand?

Comment: It should be called on the button click, rather than render. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, the code i showed will do the query when the button is clicked. You must call useLazyQuery during rendering, but that does **not** execute a query during rendering. All it does is return a function and the current state. That function will not be called until you want it to.

Comment: Is there a chance I can now store the executeQuery result to a variable?

Comment: The component will automatically rerender with a new value for `data`. If you also need that value inside the handleClick function, `executeQuery` returns a promise with the result.